# For each $X\in G_{e}$, exists a unique smooth homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to G$ with $\phi'(0)=X$ (Spivak)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

[image]

Hello. I don't quite understand the proof of Corollary 8 in a comprehensive introduction to differential geometry by Spivak. If $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to G_{e}=\mathcal{L}(G)$, by Theorem 5, exists an smooth homomorphism $\phi:U\to H$ such that ${\phi_{*}}_e\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\right)=X$ but shouldn't ${\phi_{*}}_e\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\right)=\Phi\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\right)$? although this does not make sense because it should be a real number because the definition of $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to G_e$ What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. Is being identified $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}$ ($\alpha$ is the coordinate in the basis $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}$ of $T_{t=0}(\mathbb{R})$).